# How to analyse this Gazebo with turtlebot3 on ROS2 Rolling?

Tags: ros2, gazebo-11

I've install ros2 rolling, navigation2, slam_toolbox, Gazebo 11, and the turtelbot3 in my Docker container.
Running this Gazebo launch `ros2 launch turtlebot3_gazebo turtlebot3_world.launch.py` returns these error messages:

```
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/y/.ros/log/2023-09-26-21-01-10-628365-pop23-1122
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
urdf_file_name : turtlebot3_waffle.urdf
urdf_file_name : turtlebot3_waffle.urdf
[INFO] [gzserver-1]: process started with pid [1125]
[INFO] [gzclient-2]: process started with pid [1127]
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-3]: process started with pid [1129]
[INFO] [spawn_entity.py-4]: process started with pid [1131]
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1695754871.582602597] [robot_state_publisher]: Robot initialized
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1695754871.982227902] [spawn_entity]: Spawn Entity started
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1695754871.982449226] [spawn_entity]: Loading entity XML from file /opt/ros/rolling/share/turtlebot3_gazebo/models/turtlebot3_waffle/model.sdf
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1695754871.983068964] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity, timeout = 30
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1695754871.983301368] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity
[gzserver-1] ALSA lib confmisc.c:855:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
[gzserver-1] ALSA lib conf.c:5178:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_inum returned error: No such file or directory
[gzserver-1] ALSA lib confmisc.c:422:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
[gzserver-1] ALSA lib conf.c:5178:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
[gzserver-1] ALSA lib confmisc.c:1334:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
[gzserver-1] ALSA lib conf.c:5178:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
[gzserver-1] ALSA lib conf.c:5701:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
[gzserver-1] ALSA lib pcm.c:2664:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
[gzserver-1] AL lib: (EE) ALCplaybackAlsa_open: Could not open playback device 'default': No such file or directory
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1695754872.741016925] [spawn_entity]: Calling service /spawn_entity
[gzserver-1] [INFO] [1695754872.823695242] [turtlebot3_imu]: <initial_orientation_as_reference> is unset, using default value of false to comply with REP 145 (world as orientation reference)
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1695754872.890246420] [spawn_entity]: Spawn status: SpawnEntity: Successfully spawned entity [waffle]
[gzserver-1] [INFO] [1695754873.002695193] [turtlebot3_diff_drive]: Wheel pair 1 separation set to [0.287000m]
[gzserver-1] [INFO] [1695754873.002724088] [turtlebot3_diff_drive]: Wheel pair 1 diameter set to [0.066000m]
[gzserver-1] [INFO] [1695754873.003448619] [turtlebot3_diff_drive]: Subscribed to [/cmd_vel]
[gzserver-1] [INFO] [1695754873.005967828] [turtlebot3_diff_drive]: Advertise odometry on [/odom]
[gzserver-1] [INFO] [1695754873.008795563] [turtlebot3_diff_drive]: Publishing odom transforms between [odom] and [base_footprint]
[gzserver-1] [INFO] [1695754873.015334446] [turtlebot3_joint_state]: Going to publish joint [wheel_left_joint]
[gzserver-1] [INFO] [1695754873.015355489] [turtlebot3_joint_state]: Going to publish joint [wheel_right_joint]
[INFO] [spawn_entity.py-4]: process has finished cleanly [pid 1131]
[gzclient-2] gzclient: /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:728: typename boost::detail::sp_member_access<T>::type boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator->() const [with T = gazebo::rendering::Camera; typename boost::detail::sp_member_access<T>::type = gazebo::rendering::Camera*]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.
[ERROR] [gzclient-2]: process has died [pid 1127, exit code -6, cmd 'gzclient'].
```

Based on my analysis, the Gazebo client has crashed due to the assertion. But what can be the reason? or this is because I missed something in the configuration? Why does the Gazebo server need ALSA lib?

Note, if I execute this command `ros2 launch nav2_bringup tb3_simulation_launch.py headless:=False` from the nav2 documentation in the getting started section, it works. I can see the robot and the lidar scan in the Gazebo simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sourcing the Gazebo's setup by running `source /usr/share/gazebo/setup.bash` solves the issue.