Error while launching my turtlebot3 in Gazebo
This error is shown to me:
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/eslam/.ros/log/2024-04-09-06-14-31-875924-eslam-ashraf-23793
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
urdf_file_name : turtlebot3_waffle.urdf
urdf_file_name : turtlebot3_waffle.urdf
[INFO] [gzserver-1]: process started with pid [23794]
[INFO] [gzclient-2]: process started with pid [23796]
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-3]: process started with pid [23798]
[INFO] [spawn_entity.py-4]: process started with pid [23800]
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1712636072.788697666] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_footprint
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1712636072.788785873] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1712636072.788799352] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_scan
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1712636072.788809828] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment camera_depth_frame
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1712636072.788820164] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment camera_depth_optical_frame
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1712636072.788830570] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment camera_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1712636072.788840627] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment camera_rgb_frame
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1712636072.788850475] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment camera_rgb_optical_frame
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1712636072.788860881] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment caster_back_left_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1712636072.788871007] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment caster_back_right_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1712636072.788880994] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment imu_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1712636072.788890912] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment wheel_left_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1712636072.788901038] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment wheel_right_link
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1712636073.061837406] [spawn_entity]: Spawn Entity started
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1712636073.062128776] [spawn_entity]: Loading entity XML from file /home/eslam/colcon/install/turtlebot3_gazebo/share/turtlebot3_gazebo/models/turtlebot3_waffle/model.sdf
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1712636073.062801398] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity, timeout = 30
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1712636073.063066578] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1712636073.566995649] [spawn_entity]: Calling service /spawn_entity
[gzserver-1] [INFO] [1712636073.750727485] [turtlebot3_imu]: <initial_orientation_as_reference> is unset, using default value of false to comply with REP 145 (world as orientation reference)
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1712636073.844648286] [spawn_entity]: Spawn status: SpawnEntity: Successfully spawned entity [waffle]
[gzserver-1] [INFO] [1712636073.959514818] [turtlebot3_diff_drive]: Wheel pair 1 separation set to [0.287000m]
[gzserver-1] [INFO] [1712636073.959572924] [turtlebot3_diff_drive]: Wheel pair 1 diameter set to [0.066000m]
[gzserver-1] [INFO] [1712636073.960416025] [turtlebot3_diff_drive]: Subscribed to [/cmd_vel]
[gzserver-1] [INFO] [1712636073.961784666] [turtlebot3_diff_drive]: Advertise odometry on [/odom]
[gzserver-1] [INFO] [1712636073.963485604] [turtlebot3_diff_drive]: Publishing odom transforms between [odom] and [base_footprint]
[gzserver-1] [INFO] [1712636073.970622697] [turtlebot3_joint_state]: Going to publish joint [wheel_left_joint]
[gzserver-1] [INFO] [1712636073.970652239] [turtlebot3_joint_state]: Going to publish joint [wheel_right_joint]
[INFO] [spawn_entity.py-4]: process has finished cleanly [pid 23800]
[gzclient-2] gzclient: /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:728: typename boost::detail::sp_member_access<T>::type boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator->() const [with T = gazebo::rendering::Camera; typename boost::detail::sp_member_access<T>::type = gazebo::rendering::Camera*]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.
[ERROR] [gzclient-2]: process has died [pid 23796, exit code -6, cmd 'gzclient'].

Gazebo version is 11.10.2
How can I fix that error?

@IsakMartinSimbolon - Please see this comment for an easier way to add code formatting :-)

This looks like the same error as https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/104352/how-to-analyse-this-gazebo-with-turtlebot3-on-ros2-rolling slightly different robot but same error string.

In the future you'll find that you can get better help if you add more context following the new question guide: https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1302/robotics-stack-exchange-question-checklist

If you are sure that your models path is known to gazebo then run . /usr/share/gazebo/setup.sh and then start Gazebo.
